# Given an arbitrary pair of origin & destination, how do I design a system that can effectively query all paths that cross the pair from a GPS dataset?

Tags: database-design, performance, query-performance

**Data**
I have a data set containing more than 8000 taxi drivers' GPS information, including time stamp, longitude, latitude, speed.

**Objective**
I intend to design a system which can query all taxi trajectories that cross any given pair of origin and destination and output these trajectories effectively.

**Question**
The queried origin-destination pair is random, lengths of trajectories (number of the pairs of longitude and latitude) do vary, not very structured, how could I achieve the objective?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A DB with spatial capabilities built-in should be able to do that. One option would be [PostGIS](http://postgis.net/). Check out this [link](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.1/using_postgis_dbmanagement.html#examples_spatial_sql) for example queries using it.

Comment: Thank you, you let me know there is a spatial SQL, I will carefully read the related pages to figure it out.